# Chrome extension modify suggest and search urls

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, search, google-chrome-extension

I have this extension that changes user's default search provider:

```
"chrome_settings_overrides" : {
    "homepage" : "http://example.com/",

    "search_provider" : {
        "name": "Example Search",
        "is_default" : true,
        "encoding" : "UTF-8",
        "favicon_url": "http://example.com/favicon.png",
        "keyword" : "obifind",
        "search_url" : "http://example.com/?q={searchTerms}&gid=DWB020344",
        "suggest_url" : "http://example.com/suggest.php?q={searchTerms}&gid=DWB020344"
    },
    "startup_pages" : ["http://example.com"]
},
```

`search_url` and `suggest_url` are fixed and they are working.

However, when my extension is installed and `background.js` is runned for the first time, an `uid` is generated and stored in `localStorage`. I need for this `uid` to also be sent in query with `search_url` and `suggest_url` like if `search_url` is like one above:

`http://example.com/?q={searchTerms}&gid=DWB020344`

i need it to be like this:

`http://example.com/?q={searchTerms}&gid=DWB020344&uid=00445c2e-6aca-11e6-8b77-86f30ca893d3`.

How do I pass that extra parameter when user searches something in url bar?

Comment: You could try to employ `webRequest` API to redirect matching URLs if they don't already include the UID.

Comment: As an aside, that seems like unethical tracking. Consider obeying `navigator.doNotTrack`.

Comment: @Xan I am not sure where I am wrong, i am using webRequest API but it just does not want to append it. `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener` should have callback that returns an object that contains property `redirectUrl`, am I right?

Comment: No; check the [Catblock sample](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#catblock) in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should do the trick, using [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) in the background page:

```
var uid = localStorage["uid"]; // Have it ready for max performance of webRequest

if (navigator.doNotTrack != 1) { // Let's not be evil, OK?
  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
      if (details.url.indexOf("uid=") == -1) { // If no UID yet
        return { // return a BlockingResponse object
          redirectUrl: request.url.replace("?", "?uid=" + uid + "&")
          // Add uid as first parameter, to make sure we don't run into URL fragments
        };
      }
    },
    {urls: ["http://example.com/?*gid=DWB020344*"]},
    ["blocking"]
  );
}
```

Requires `"webRequest"` and `"webRequestBlocking"` permissions and a persistent background page (can't use `"persistent": false`).